# How to fixe itemCount to get data from firestore to list view

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**I have Listview.builder that contains data from an array in Firestore that an array in subcollection my structure data Like this
But when to showing that array to Listview its showing the only first, which is 0. I need to get all data In array to list view.  How can I fixe itemCount to get all data?**

```
Collcetion 
-Institute
--document
---PI3naj7N7GgwlDSjK3rV0Twiu2S2
----subCollcetion 
------Ravs 
-------documentsubCollcetion 
English 
field
Ravs name :English 

item array 
0 
Contains Data Map 
1
Contains Data Map
2
Contains Data Map
.
.
.
.
```

**this my function**

```
 StreamBuilder(
          stream:Firestore.instance.collection("Institute").document(
              'PI3naj7N7GgwlDSjK3rV0Twiu2S2').collection("Ravs")
              .where('Ravs name',isEqualTo:'English ' ).snapshots() ,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

            if (snapshot.hasError) return Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                'it has error ',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),),


            );
            return snapshot.hasData

                ? Scaffold(
              appBar: new AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.brown[600],),
              body:Card(
             child:ListView.builder(
              itemCount:snapshot.data.documents.length,

              itemBuilder: (_,index){
                  DocumentSnapshot ds =snapshot.data.documents[index];
                return Directionality(
                   textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                   child:Card(
                    child:InkWell(
                    onTap: (){

                },
                   child:Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                         new Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                           width: 500,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(150)),

                          ),
                         alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        child:
 FadeInImage.assetNetwork(fit: 
BoxFit.fill,placeholder:
 'assets/images/image.jpg', 
image: ds.data['item'][index]['Iamge path']),

                         ),

                        new Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(" name Rav:${ds.data['item'][index]['Ravs_name'] }",textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title),
                                Text("Date:${ds.data['item'][index]['Rav_Date']} ",textAlign: TextAlign.right, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5))),
                              ],
                            )
                        )    
                         ],

                   )
                )
                   )
                );

              }

            ),
              )
            ) : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          },

        );
```

Answer (score 0):

This structure you are presenting seems to have collection in collection which is not possible. However, as this is possible to run your code, I assume that in the structure `Ravs` is a subcollection of documents that have field `Rav name`.

So the code creates query with `.where('Ravs name',isEqualTo:'English ')`, this create snapshot of documents which I believe contains only one document. So bellow statement :

`itemCount:snapshot.data.documents.length`

equals to 1, and this is why you get one iteration in your `itemBuilder`.

I do not have any chance to test it, but I think that solution should be:

1. change `itemCount:snapshot.data.documents[0].data['item'].length` - or something like that - to  give you proper number of items to iterate trough.
2. First line of itemBuilder should be set to: `DocumentSnapshot ds =snapshot.data.documents[0];` This is because you want to iterate over array in the only one document.

If it do not work at once you should play with it... I am basing this on the fact that what you presented is possible to run :).

I hope it will help!

Comment: Your solution  not working is it possible to query subcollcetion   without using where means   can query array in Ravs without using where Because  I tried using query without where but I have error  ("item") null

Comment: Were you able to create working code that provides wrong data ?  or maybe there are some errors that you can share?

Comment: I just make code query Like this                                                 Firestore.instance.collection("Institute").document(
        'PI3naj7N7GgwlDSjK3rV0Twiu2S2').collection("Ravs")
        .document('Englsih').snapshots(),   and check if has data i'ts print on console has data  but when I need to access to the filed  showing me error the filed its null

Comment: This should work as well, even better. I thought that due to some reason you don't want to use document reference. In this situation I would build tiny app just to be able to play with how to  create proper reference to your object...